How can I generate my ids automatically with json-server? Does it no longer generate?
I'm using json-server as a fake api, and when making the POST request, my ids are not being generated automatically, note that they are already as a String, which is as recommended in the documentation.
My class user
export class User {
  public id: String = ''
  public name: String = ''
  public phone: String = ''
  public email: String = ''
  public cpf: String = ''
  public password: String = ''
}

from 10 to 13 I manually put the data in my db.json, after that we can notice that the id is not coming automatically
{
"id": "10",
"firstName": "Bruno",
"email": "brunohauck@gmail.com",
"phone": "323",
"cpf": "05126769685",
"password": "fdsfds"
  },
{
"id": "11",
"firstName": "Bruno",
"email": "brunohauck@gmail.com",
"phone": "323",
"cpf": "05126769685",
"password": "fdsfds"
 },
{
"id": "12",
"firstName": "Bruno",
"email": "brunohauck@gmail.com",
"phone": "323",
"cpf": "05126769685",
"password": "fdsfds"
  },
 {
"id": "13",
"firstName": "Bruno",
"email": "brunohauck@gmail.com",
"phone": "323",
"cpf": "05126769685",
"password": "fdsfds"
 },
{
"id": "",
"name": "teste",
"phone": "1111111111",
"email": "teste@gmail.com",
"cpf": "18361591885",
"password": "111"
 }
]

on the npm website it says id is always a string and will be generated for you if missing
json-server npm

I'm pretty sure you have posted this question once already, but now deleted it. And again, where does it state that the json-server generates an Id for you?

I reposted because I didn't get any help, the website says this, this is your answer " on the npm website it says id is always a string and will be generated for you if missing" @T.Jami

can you please be more precise and perhaps share a link of the docs in which states the Id is supposed to be auto generated

Do you mean that json-server doesn't do this? So how do I generate the ids? @T.jami

I don't know, that's why I am asking you. You are claiming that json-server generates an Id automatically for you. Have you read the documentation? if not, I strongly encourage you to read the documentation.

I already sent the link to the website that says it generates the ID automatically, npm itself says this, how can you vote my question as negative when you didn't answer my question? @T.jami

The reason I, or the previous user in your last question, asked whether you have read the documentation and, if so, where it states that an Id will be automatically generated, is that as someone seeking help, it’s important to at least try to do some research and put effort into framing the question. Remember, the Stack Overflow community is built on volunteers. You can find more tips on how to ask a good question.
I have read the initial section of the documentation, and it clearly states that the Id must be set in the request body. The only requirement for the Id is that it must not be a duplicate.

Id values are not mutable. Any id value in the body of your PUT or
PATCH request will be ignored. Only a value set in a POST request will
be respected, but only if not already taken.
~ json-server: Getting started

Additionally, there was a closed GitHub issue where it was explicitly stated that there is no auto-increment functionality. However another user added how you could possibly add such a functionality.
The link you provided mentions that if the id property is missing, it will automatically add an id property to your object. However, this doesn’t clarify whether the property is assigned a valid value or when exactly the id is added. Is it added during the request, in the response, or only within the database? Perhaps open a github issue and/or contribute to the project.

Your answer doesn't make any sense and didn't manage to clear my doubt. @T.jami

@vinudev where does the doubt come from? that is exactly what I was trying to figure out. You can't find in the docs anything that mentions auto generating Ids. You have tested it out and couldn't get auto generated Ids. How about you just create an actual backend and you wont have these kind of issues?
